# Center align the nav-bar content in Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to centre the nav-bar links. But sadly i haven't had much luck so far. I've tried to use navbar-justified but that just throws every thing out of proportion.

[here is the code](http://www.bootply.com/oXscVZgIaV).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you wanted to center everything to the center. The easiest way is to use `display: inline-block` and then `text-align: center` on the parent element. Then also reset `float` to use the default aligment:

See you updated demo: http://www.bootply.com/iu9NOXfmEV

Answer (score -1):

Make the container `inline-block` to get the width of the content, and align the `navbar` elements. To get rid of the gap underneath use `vertical-align: top`.

To avoid changes when collapsed add media query:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
   .navbar {
      text-align:center;
   }
   .navbar .container-fluid {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
   }
}
```

You can see [here](http://www.bootply.com/wOcmsBCx3c)

Comment: It would be smart to reset the floats so that the height of the nav items match the height of the navbar. Other than that, this is a fair solution.

Comment: @Charlie you are correct. I didnt notice the gap. Another way of fixing it is to set a `vertical-align: top` on the container as I updated my answer. Thanks for pointing out